# Display a repository of which I am collaborator on profile

Tags: git, github, open-source

My friend and I are working on a project we designed together. My friend created a repository for the project and I am a collaborator so I can easily add changes. But is there a way to display this repo on my profile?

Comment: The answer is "yes". Also, the true answer belongs to the [Henrique's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407615/3702377)

Comment: I change "contributor" to "collaborator", which is what I think you meant. Otherwise, we should close this question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854230/contributed-repositories-not-listed-in-my-github-repositories

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A repo will only show up under the user or org that "owns" it. Here are three options for you. If you both own the work, you should probably go with option 3.

### option 1: fork a copy to your profile

But what you *can* do is fork it. It essentially clones the repo into your account, with all the commits. Since contributor info is based on the commits, it will show the same contributor information.

Since you were added as a collaborator, you have direct access to the original repo and can push commits to it directly. You can keep your clone in sync with the original with the recently aded `fetch upstream` button:

[image]

This means you do not need to do steps 2-5 of Henrique's answer. Not unless you prefer pushing your changes to your fork first, and then doing pull requests from it to your friend's.

### option 2: pin the repo owned by your friend to your profile

Another thing you can do is to pin a repo so that it appears on the top of your profile. You can pin either the original or your fork:

[image]

### option 3: create an org to reflect shared ownership

If the repo shouldn't belong to one person, create an org and move the repo to the org, and make both of you admins of the org.

Answer (score 3):

1. You have to fork the repository and then you can clone it into your computer.
2. Add your changes, "git add", "git commit" and "git push"
3. Now your changes will be on your profile, inside the repo.
4. Create a new Pull Request
5. If your friend accept the pull request the code(changes) will be merged.

:) done!

> OBS: If you don't know how to make a pull request read the following article 
>   https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/

Comment: just add another tip to this answer: when your friend accepts your pull request, you can pin that repo in your profile well.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari nice tip. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If that repo is set to 'public', you can:

1. [Click on the top right + button on your Github page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24hfr.png)
2. Click "Import repository" option in the dropdown menu
3. Paste the github URL of the original repo into "Your old repository's clone URL"
4. Type a name for the 'new' repo that will appear on your account.
5. Select begin import and wait till it's done.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20230728013959/https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/pinning-items-to-your-profile), as long as you have made a contribution to the repo, you should be able to pin it to your profile page. So if you haven't already, just make a contribution to the repo, such as a commit.

If that fails, you can at least create a fork of the repo and pin that fork to your profile.