# Contributed repositories not listed in my GitHub repositories

Tags: github, open-source

I have made several pull requests that were merged into a public repository. My name is listed as a contributor but I can't find the repository in my GitHub repositories. The only way is to create a fork but it would show up as a "forked from" repository.

When I visited the profile of other contributors I saw that they had the original repository on their profile. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply follow these steps:

1. Go to your GitHub profile.
2. Click on `Customize your pins`:

[image: Step 2]

3. In the `Edit pinned items` dialog, you can select the repositories you have contributed to, which will display them on your GitHub profile.

[image: Step 3]

Comment: A small thing that I have noticed is that the contributed repo have a prefix of the user who created it e.g. `torvalds/linux` instead of `linux`. Can we change this too?

Comment: The only way to only have the name of the repository is to fork it.