# Displaying collaborated repositories on my Github

Tags: git, github

I contributed to one of my friend's public repo. How do I also display the same repo on my own Github page? I still want to keep the commit history as well as the list of contributors that shows on the repo page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display a repository of which I am collaborator on profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407200/display-a-repository-of-which-i-am-collaborator-on-profile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A repo will only show up under the user or org that "owns" it.

But what you *can* do is fork it. It essentially clones the repo into your account, with all the commits. Since contributor info is based on the commits, it will show the same contributor information.

If you want to keep that data in sync as new commits are made to the source repo, you can use the `fetch upstream` button:

[image]

### create an org to reflect shared ownership

If the repo shouldn't belong to one person, create an org and move the repo to the org, and make both of you admins of the org.

Comment: I found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407200/display-a-repository-of-which-i-am-contributor-on-profile. Are you saying basically just follow these steps?

Comment: No, you only have to do step 1, since the `fetch upstream` button has been added recently.

Comment: thanks and you mean "sync" not sink right?

Comment: yes, thanks. i added more info to my answer.