# How to make my repo appear on my friends' GitHub profiles?

Tags: github

I have a little problem.

I just finished a small project in java with my friends, we used GitHub to be more professional and to be more efficient (I created the repo etc). Now that we finished the project I changed it to public and pushed the last modification.

But the problem is that the project doesn't show up in my friends GitHub. Of course they were Collaborators, I added them personally.

How can I make the repo appear in their GitHub?

I tried to re-add them but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [Inigo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43407200/9592692) answer:

> **"A repo will only show up under the user or org that "owns" it."**

So the quickest solution is to ask them to fork it from your account. That way, the repo will appear under their ***username*** as a clone from the main/root repo!

**Things you can try:**

- Confirm that your repository's visibility is set to “Public.” Go to your repository's settings, locate the “Danger Zone” section, and check that the “Change repository visibility” option is set to “Public.”
- Verify that you are the owner of the repository, not just a collaborator. Ownership allows you to control the repository's visibility and settings.

Answer (score 0):

*You* can't make your repo appear on their profile, but *they* can. They would need to follow [Display a repository of which I am collaborator on profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43407200/11107541). Quoting my answer there:

> According to [the docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20230728013959/https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/pinning-items-to-your-profile), as long as you have made a contribution to the repo, you should be able to pin it to your profile page. So if you haven't already, just make a contribution to the repo, such as a commit.
>
> If that fails, you can at least create a fork of the repo and pin that fork to your profile.