# GitHub Collaboration

Tags: github

Someone sent me an invitation as a collaborator and I've accepted the invite. But my challenge is, I don't see it on my repository if I'm not signed into my account. And I shared my GitHub link to someone to check out my repositories and he also didn't see the project that I was invited to. And it's a public repo. Please what can I do, because the person that I sent the link to is contemplating on giving me and internship or not

I tried checking my GitHub repos on another phone to see if I'll see the project I was invited to, and it still didn't show. And now I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407200/display-a-repository-of-which-i-am-collaborator-on-profile), and the accepted answer suggests that you can:

1. fork the repository to your own account.
2. pin the repository to your profile
3. create an organization and move the repository to the organization.

i think these are good options for you to make the project visible on your profile. you can find more details on how to do each of these steps in the linked answer.